# How Does R read nodatavalue tags from a geotiff - R Raster package

Tags: r, raster, no-data

I am running into an unusual outcome with raster no data values in R.
Code below -- I have a raster that has a no data value that I import (-9999). QGIS reads the nodatavalue, arcgis too. R, when it reads in the geotiff, assigned the nodata value to -INF.

I don't know why. But I decided to try to make one from scratch - and SAME RESULT. what is wrong with my process? How can I ensure that R reads in the nodatavalues properly?

NOTE: my example below is a created raster / geotiff. But I'm actually importing geotiffs that are quite large produced by an organization. So I don't have control over how they are written but I could ask them to adjust tags if need be.

```
library(raster)
#create a raster from the matrix
myRaster1 <- raster(nrow=4, ncol=4)

#assign some random data to the raster
myRaster1[]<- 1:ncell(myRaster1)

myRaster1[5] <- -9999

#ensure the data have some decimals
myRaster1[2] <- 34.5

#assign no data value to raster
myRaster1@file@nodatavalue <- -9999

#make sure it worked
NAvalue(myRaster1)
myRaster1@file@nodatavalue

#view attributes of the raster
myRaster1


#write out raster
#write the geotiff - change overwrite=TRUE to overwrite=FALSE if you want to make sure you don't overwrite your files!
writeRaster(myRaster1,"newDel.tif","GTiff", overwrite=TRUE)


#import raster
newr <- raster("newDel.tif")
newr@file@nodatavalue
```

Thank you for any advice / explanation as to how R imports tags from a geotiff.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thank you for creating a reproducible example, but the example you created is perhaps not the most helpful. Assigning values to a slot (names behind a `@`) is not "legal". Unless you have advanced knowledge of the Raster objects, you should use the user-interface (functions, methods). So, never do this:

```
myRaster1@file@nodatavalue <- -9999
```

The value in this slot is for internal consumption only; and only relevant for objects that get values from disk. Likewise,

```
newr@file@nodatavalue
# [1] -Inf
```

does not mean that `NA` values in `"newDel.tif"` are stored that way.

To set a certain value when writing, use the options available in `writeRaster`.

Now, your problem seems to be that you have files with values -9999 that should be considered as `NA`, and somehow this does not happen. It is odd that it would work in QGIS because the same info and same underlying software is used (`GDAL`). But here is a how you can deal with that:

Create a geotiff file with values -9999 that are not recognized as `NA`

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(nrow=5, ncol=5)
values(r) <- 1:25
r[1:5] <- -9999
writeRaster(r, 'test.tif', overwrite=TRUE)
```

Your situation:

```
x <- raster('test.tif')
plot(x)
```

This will probably fix it:

```
NAvalue(x) <- -9999
plot(x)
```

Comment: hi @RobertH Thank you for the response! The issue that i'm having (i'm not sure how to make this reprod) is that R is NOT reading in the geotiff tag for nodatavalue. I just tried to represent that above in a reproduc work flow. When the file comes in, it reassigned NAValue -> -Inf . i would like to understand why that happens. Even using the example you provided above, when i reimport the raster, NAvalue(raster) is -INF not -9999. So it seems that R does not read in the NA Value properly. Very open to any feedback to ensure R reads in the geotiff tags properly.

Comment: Searching the github cran mirror for nodatavalue and -Inf may be helpful. [link to this search](https://github.com/cran/raster/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=nodatavalue+-INF&type=Code)

Comment: It normally works. Probably there is something strange about your file. Or perhaps you need to update R/(r)gdal. Can you make one of the files available for download? Or else email it to the maintainer or the `raster` package (that is me).

Comment: To explain a bit more. tiff files are read via `rgdal`. rgdal returns `NA` values (not flag values that need to be replaced with NA). Hence the `-Inf` value in the RasterLayer objects that you are looking at is immaterial in this workflow as it is is not used in any way. You could inspect the output of `rgdal::GDALinfo('file.tif')` to see what it reports for NA flag vale.

Comment: @RobertH the explanation above helped immensely (as did the email). I didn't understand what was happening under the hood. Now I do. So I will use GDALinfo on the file to view the nodata value. Then when i write the raster, i can use NAflag= to assign the nodata value that i want for the output tif. THANK YOU for helping me work through understanding this! I appreciate the time spent!

Comment: @LeahWasser, if you can answer this question it would be useful for future readers having related problems (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67268745/3-39999999999999996e38-nodata-value-and-raster-r )

Comment: oh gosh @BenBolker this was 5+ years ago. i'm not sure i still have that email exchange as i switched jobs but i will look!