# -3.39999999999999996e+38 NODATA value and raster R

Tags: r, r-raster, geotiff

*NODATA* values of some geotiffs (*-3.39999999999999996e+38*) is recognized as *-Inf* in R.

I use raster package to read the files and generate a raster stack.

After raster calculations using *calc* , *NODATA* values are converted to *0*.

Is there any way to retain *NODATA* flag value.

I think it's a float precision limitation.

Data are from https://www.worldclim.org/data/v1.4/cmip5_30s.html

This is my R code.

```
library(raster) 
library(rasterVis) 

tiffs <- list.files(".", sprintf("%s.*tif","clip" ), full.names = T)

s <-stack(tiffs)
NAvalue(s)
levelplot(s,margin=FALSE)


composite <- raster::calc(s,sum, na.rm=T)

levelplot(composite,margin=FALSE)
```

Comment: This question might be better for gis.stackexchange.com  .. but do you just need to reclassify the 0's to NODATA or you want to retain those from the start?

Comment: No, 0's is different from NODATA value  (-3.39999999999999996e+38). I want to keep it as 0's and NODATA as -3.39999999999999996e+38

Comment: Any chance this is `-3.39e308` (not `-3.39e38`), which *would* be beyond R's floating-point max negative value (`.Machine$double.xmin`) ? As @RobertHijmans says, we really need a [mcve] before we can help very much ...  Are these values converted to 0 after importing your data and *before* doing the calculations, or only after the calculations? What calculations are you doing? (For example, `1/Inf` or `-1/Inf` in R result in zero, but converting to `NA` (R's `NODATA` analogue) should preserve the missingness ...

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33446590/how-does-r-read-nodatavalue-tags-from-a-geotiff-r-raster-package

Answer (score 5):

The confusion stems from how `sum` works. I will use an example file that ships with R for easier reproducibility

```
library(raster)
f <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
r <- raster(f)
s <- stack(r, r*2)

## equivalent to calc(s, sum)
sum(s, na.rm=FALSE)
#class      : RasterLayer 
#dimensions : 115, 80, 9200  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#resolution : 40, 40  (x, y)
#values     : 416.1212, 5208.174  (min, max)

sum(s, na.rm=TRUE)
#class      : RasterLayer 
#dimensions : 115, 80, 9200  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#resolution : 40, 40  (x, y)
#values     : 0, 5208.174  (min, max)
```

Note the difference in minimum values (0 vs 416.1212). That is because of how `sum` works.

```
sum(c(NA, NA))
#[1] NA
sum(c(NA, NA), na.rm=TRUE)
#[1] 0
```

The sum of nothing is zero, whereas the sum of one or more `NA`s is `NA`.

In your case with the worldclim data there is no reason to use `na.rm=TRUE`. Otherwise you could use `mask` after `calc`.

This is not the case with `terra`:

```
library(terra)
x <- rast(s)
sum(x, na.rm=TRUE)
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 115, 80, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 40, 40  (x, y)
#extent      : 178400, 181600, 329400, 334000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=sterea +lat_0=52.1561605555556 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
#source      : memory 
#name        :      sum 
#min value   : 416.1212 
#max value   : 5208.174 

app(x, sum, na.rm=TRUE)
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 115, 80, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 40, 40  (x, y)
#extent      : 178400, 181600, 329400, 334000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=sterea +lat_0=52.1561605555556 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
#source      : memory 
#name        :      sum 
#min value   : 416.1212 
#max value   : 5208.174
```

And even thought that is somewhat inconsistent with base R, I think it is better that way in the context of raster data. The get the same behavior as base-R and `raster` you could do

```
app(x, function(i) sum(i, na.rm=TRUE))
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 115, 80, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 40, 40  (x, y)
#extent      : 178400, 181600, 329400, 334000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=sterea +lat_0=52.1561605555556 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
#source      : memory 
#name        :    lyr.1 
#min value   :        0 
#max value   : 5208.174
```

Comment: While useful, this is closer to a comment than an answer ...

Comment: You use the pattern `"clip.*tif"` --- How did you generate these files? (the worldclim website does not have files with names like that)

Comment: I clipped them with QGIS. You can download clipped from here https://github.com/kokkytos/demo

Comment: It was so simple... Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Raster objects can hold `NA` values.

Assume the object is called `x`. Then you could e.g. set all values below a threshold to `NA`.

```
x[x < -3.39999999999999996e+37] <- NA
```

Comment: or `x[ !is.finite(x)] <- NA` ?

Comment: @BenBolker That would also set large positive values that are treated as `Inf` to `NA`.

Answer (score 0):

data ending with e+38 are null points in geotiff files